# Find a button on a web page looking for part of its InnerText string in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013, coded-ui-tests

I am writing automated tests for a website. On the website there is a button that will have the inner text "All Open" + four random digits. For example: "All Open2957". Is there a way to find the button using only the "All Open" part of the string?

This does not work since the string is missing the four last digits:

```
HtmlSpan uIAllOpenPane = new HtmlSpan();
uIAllOpenPane.SearchProperties[HtmlDiv.PropertyNames.InnerText] = "All Open";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When trying to locate the controller I only got the `FailedToPerformActionOnHiddenC‌​ontrolException`. Eventually I was able to locate the DIV container that contained the controller I was trying to locate instead of focusing on finding the controller directly. After finding the container I could locate the controller using

```
HtmlSpan uIAllOpenPane = new HtmlSpan(container);
uIAllOpenPane.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlDiv.PropertyNames.InnerText, "All Open",
PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains);
```

The code from @AdrianHHH helped with the problem when part of the string is randomized each time you encounter the controller.

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is to use the `PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains` rather than `PropertyExpressionOperator.EqualTo` comparator and search for just the required text.

For recorded tests, find the control in the UI Map editor and view its properties panel. Click the "Search properties" field and then click the ellipsis. The window that appears allows the comparator and the required text to be altered.

For hand coded tests use code of the form:

```
uIAllOpenPane.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlDiv.PropertyNames.InnerText,
    "All Open",
    PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains);
```

According to [this Microsoft blog](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/af0267bd-4f70-40ac-8374-a168379cb217/difference-between-searchproperties-and-searchpropertiesaddnew-propertyexpression-?forum=vsautotest) the array index style (ie with `[` and `]`) as used in the question  internally calls the `SearchProperties.Add(...)` but that style has no variation to specify `...Contains`, so call the `...Add(...)` explicitly.

Comment: I tried your edit both for recorded tests and hand coded ones. The test does not seem to find the button at all even though this should work.

Comment: @hardyfelix There may be some other search property that is preventing the button from being found. The Coded UI recorder adds lots of search properties to the search, many can be deleted if there are problems. It adds lots of them to try and ensure the correct item is found when the application changes to have more items on screen or when multiple copies of the application are running. Check the other search properties and see if any should be removed.

Comment: Whatever I search for I always get the Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.FailedToPerformActionOnHiddenControlException:
Do you know anything about this exception? I have tried to limit the amount of search properties to a minimum and it still cannot find a single button on that particular page.

Comment: @hardyfelix There are lots of web pages asking for help on that exception and lots of good advice but your original question asked about something else. If your real question is about that exception then you should have stated it in the question.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I thought that my problem had to do with me not being able to search for part of a string. But since in reality nothing is searchable on that particular page I am facing another problem. I'll be looking elsewhere for solution to that exception

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
 Button allOpenButton =  (Button)BrowserWindow.ExecuteScript("allOpenButton = function(){var found; $('input[type=\"button\"]').each(function(){ if($(this).val().indexOf('All Open') > -1){ found = $(this);};}); return found;}; return allOpenButton();");
```